# Gaslimit can not be set -1 in ink4.0.0

Tags: ink, smart-contract

## Problem

I upgraded my project to ink4.0.0, and upgrate @polkadot/api-contract to the latest version, then I encountered an error when sending transaction.

```js
Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding contracts.call:: Struct: failed on args: {"dest":"MultiAddress","value":"Lookup78","gas_limit":"Lookup93","storage_deposit_limit":"Option<Compact<u128>>","data":"Bytes"}:: Struct: failed on gas_limit: Compact<Weight>:: u64: Negative number passed to unsigned type
```

## Code

My code is like this

```js
let value = 0;
let gasLimit = -1;
await contract.tx[methodName]({ value, gasLimit }, ...arguments).signAndSend(sender, (result) => {
    if (result.status.isInBlock) {
        console.log('in a block');
    } else if (result.status.isFinalized) {
        console.log('finalized');
    }
});
```

It worked well for ink3.0.

I wonder if I have to estimate gas in ink4.0.0, or I can set gaslimit 10**12?

Answer (score 3):

`-1` is not a valid value for a **transaction**. For a transaction you should dry run the contract first and set the `gas_limit` for the transaction to the `gas_required` field as returned by the dry run.

As a side node: `-1` is not a valid value for the dry run either as it is an unsigned number in substrate. I assume polkadot.js transforms this `-1` into some big number for you.